# How to upload a excel sheet and to read its data row by row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filereader

I am getting an excel file from the user, I have this file upload tag and a upload button, how can I store the file in my project folder and how to read row by row in the excel. THe excel will have 3 columns: name, Email, PhNo.

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
 protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

the user will upload a xls file

Comment: Is it definitely excel format? Or is it a csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For read Excel:

1. [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)
2. [excelpackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)

Save file upload

1. [Uploading Files Using the File Field Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478971.aspx)
2. [Uploading Files in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)
3. [FileUpload.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably not the answer you're looking for, I found the following component very easy to work with on a recent project when recently asked to do a fairly complex excel import.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx

It allows some really neat functionality such as named ranges, lookups etc in both import and export mode. 
It could be worth looking into if you want an out of the box solution to do the heavy lifting for you.

On the flip side of the same project I was asked to replicate this functionality with an access import/export and ended up writing some functions using the ADOX libraries, these can be used with excel in a similar way, so if you're after something similar it would be worth looking into this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303814

In a nutshell, both of these methods allow you to end up with a sensible C# object, such as a datatable, which you can then use to fiddling about with the data as you please.